# Combining results into one object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through a set of inputs. I need to tally up the grouped totals. The inputs below to one of three categories.

How do I go about combining the values up relevant to three categories?

```
var compoundedArray = new Array();

    holder.find(".dataset input").each(function(index) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var dataType = $(this).data("type");

        var localObj = {};

        localObj[dataType] = val;
        compoundedArray.push(localObj);
    });
```

I have an object like this

```
[
    {
    "growth":30
    },
    {
    "growth": 40
    },
    {
    "other": 20
    }
]
```

how do I loop through the object to produce something like

```
[
    {
        "growth": 70
    },
    {
        "other": 20
    }
]
```

if I looped over the initial array object

```
for (var i = 0; i < compoundedArray.length; i++) {
console.log(compoundedArray[i]);
}
```

how would I go about checking to ensure I don't have duplicates - and that I can tally up the results?

Ideally the resulting format may be the best

```
var array = [
    "matching": 50,
    "growth": 20    
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [
    "matching": 50,
    "growth": 20    
]
```

is not valid JS, but you can create an object of the form

```
var obj = {
    "matching": 50,
    "growth": 20
};
```

And that's pretty easy to do, just use an object from the very beginning:

```
var result = {};

holder.find(".dataset input").each(function(index) {
    var val = +$(this).val(); // use unary plus to convert to number
    var dataType = $(this).data("type");

    result[dataType] = (result[dataType] || 0) + val;
});
```

---

Further reading material:

- [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [Eloquent JavaScript - Data structures: Objects and Arrays](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html)

Comment: I think thats nearly there. but I am getting string values instead of ints.. result Object {growth: "040520", matching: "0302020202020", other: "020"}

Comment: Then it seems you did not change the line `var val = +$(this).val();`. I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an object (not array) with unique keys.

```
var compoundedObj = {};

$(".dataset input", holder).each(function() {
    var dataType = $(this).data("type");
    if(!compoundedObj.hasOwnProperty(dataType)) {
        compoundedObj[dataType] = 0;
    }
    compoundedObj[dataType] += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
```

In this way you'll get an object like this:

```
{
    "growth": 70,
    "other": 20
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/qHszb/)

Comment: var resultingobject = new Array();
  
  var result = {};
  holder.find(".dataset input").each(function(index) {
   var val = $(this).val();
   var dataType = $(this).data("type");
   
   
   if(!resultingobject.hasOwnProperty(dataType)) {
    resultingobject[dataType] = 0;
   }
   resultingobject[dataType] += parseInt($(this).val(),10);  
  });

Answer (score 0):

### http://jsfiddle.net/GFwGU/

```
var original = [{"growth":30},{"growth": 40},{"other": 20}]

// object to sum all parts by key
var sums = {}
// loop through original object
for(var index in original){
    // get reference to array value (target object)
    var outer = original[index]
    // loop through keys of target object
    for(var key in outer){
        // get a reference to the value
        var value = outer[key]
        // set or add to the value on the sums object
        sums[key] = sums[key] ? sums[key] + value : value
    }
}

// create the output array
var updated = []
// loop through all the summed keys
for(var key in sums){
    // get reference to value
    var value = sums[key]
    // create empty object
    var dummy = {}
    // build object into desired format
    dummy[key] = value
    // push to output array
    updated.push(dummy)
}

// check the results
alert(JSON.stringify( updated ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var add=function (a,b){ a=a||0; b=b||0; return a+b};
var input=[ {growth:30},{growth:40},{other:20} ],output=[],temp={};

$.each(input,function(i,o){
  var n;
  for(i in o)
     {n=i;break}
  temp[n]=add(temp[n],o[n]);
});

$.each(temp,function(i,o){
  var k={};
   k[i]=o;
  output.push(k)
});
```